# The value of $x^T\Lambda x$ given $\Lambda$ is positive semidefinite

Tags: matrices, positive-semidefinite

For the value $x^T\Lambda x$, where $\Lambda$ is positive semidefinite (and it is not positive definite), what determines the maximum value of the mutiplication when the value of $x$ is given. (If $\Lambda$ is **PD**, then it should be the maximum eigen value affects the value through decomposing $x$ to a linear combination of all orthogonal eigen vectors)

Let me explain more clearly. The reason I say $x$ is given is because the norm of $x$ is not the primary concern here. Say, we can treat $\Lambda$ as a system, and here the concerned thing is the property of the system, rather than how the *input* $x$ affect the result.

Comment: In my answer below, I'm assuming you mean when you are allowed to maximize in $x$, otherwise if $x$ is fixed, then the quadratic form is just a value.

Comment: When the value of $x$ "is given," the product has a single value determined by $\Lambda$ and simple multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the largest eigenvalue will determine the maximum value of the quadratic form.  One can see this by writing $\Lambda$ by a sum of rank one matrices.
$$
\Lambda = \sum \lambda_i u_i u_i^T 
$$
where $u_i$ are the eigenvectors.  Then,
$$
x^T \Lambda x = \sum \lambda_i (x^T u_i)^2.
$$
As the $u_i$ form an orthonormal basis, the maximum is achieved by letting $x = u_i$ for $i$ corresponding to the largest eigenvalue.